# How to query a Work Item's state changes from Azure DevOps in Power bi

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, workitem

I want to track the changes of all Bug Work Item's states from Azure DevOps in Power Bi as close to live as possible. How do I get Power Bi to identify a work item which has had it's state changed recently?

In the needs simplest form, I'd like to see the state graph (shown in history view of each work item on Azure DevOps) and then add an additional rule which identifies work items that have gone through certain changes as soon as they happen/as soon as I look which will be every hour or so.

so far attempted using analytics views to identify and upload to Power Bi but the "changed date" field applies to all changes not just state changes.

Tried using azure devops queries but they don't identify previous state values.

Comment: Hi , Did you try adding State Change Date field, is it helpful for your question? If you have any question,please feel free to ask.:)

Answer (score 2):

> so far attempted using analytics views to identify and upload to Power Bi but the "changed date" field applies to all changes not just state
>   changes.

For this issue, you can add **State Change Date** field
[image]

> as soon as I look which will be every hour or so.

For this issue,I am afraid it is currently impossible to achieve.  The highest granularity possible in Analytics View of Azure Devops is Daily but for a single work item it captures on one state for single day. If there are multiple state changes in a day we loose that data and only get the latest update state row. So, currently the analytics view only shows the latest status within a day.

Here is a [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/538301/devops-analytics-view-results-incomplete.html) to explore analytics view results incomplete,please refer to Issue#2 of it.